# Unpermitted parameter: contact_requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried following along http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms because it is very close to something I am trying to create. I am currently using Rails 4.2 beta. I am really new to rails so I'm not sure where I am going wrong

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.contact_requests.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  private

    def user_params
      # strong_parameters, which requires us to tell Rails exactly which parameters
      # we want to accept in our controllers
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number, contact_requests_attributes: [:message])
      # params.require(:users).permit!
    end
end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  has_many :contact_requests
  # validate the presence of the attributes
  validates(:first_name, presence: true)
  validates(:last_name, presence: true)
  validates(:email, presence: true)
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_requests

end

class ContactRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
end
```

form:

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">Contact Us</div>
    <div class="title-caption">Reach us at (415)-911-9999</div>
    <%= form_for(@user, remote: true, id: "contact-form", class: "contact-input") do |f| %>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last name") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.email_field(:email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.telephone_field(:phone_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone number") %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input-margin col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.fields_for :contact_requests do |builder| %>
              <%= builder.text_area(:message, class: "form-control contact-margin", rows: "8", placeholder: "Message...") %>
              <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-xl") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

terminal output:

```
Started POST "/test" for ::1 at 2014-12-03 00:30:09 -0800
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"bradfffo", "last_name"=>"li", "email"=>"skdljfd@ksdjf", "phone_number"=>"123123", "contact_requests"=>{"message"=>"sdlkfjskdfdsf"}}, "commit"=>"Save User"}
Unpermitted parameter: contact_requests
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/bli1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/bli1/Development/RoR/Boothie/app/views"
):
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `determine_template'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/bli1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:114:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:231:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:87:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:750:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:257:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:558:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:645:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:83:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:103:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0.beta2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/bli1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/bli1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/bli1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/bli1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/missing_template.text.erb (0.3ms)
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  match '/send_mail', to: "home#send_mail", via: "get"



  get 'test', to: "users#new"
  post 'test', to: "users#create"
```

Comment: Hey, the first thing you should fix is to use the singular in require like this: `params.require(:user)`. If you look at the form fields names and at what the controller receives as params you will understand why. Modify this and retry.

Comment: Dude leave the form alone, leave it as `form_for(@user ...`, you create a form for the user instance, which is hold in @user.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the `id` attribute for `contact_requests`, you need to modify the `user_params` method, see below

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number, contact_requests_attributes: [:id, :message])
```

I have added `id` attribute to `contact_requests_attributes`

Also, you need to use `:user` instead of `:users`, I have corrected it above!

Give it a try!

Comment: Use `:user` instead of `:users`, check my edited answer

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I am having a routes issue now http://postimg.org/image/c5dx49dod/

Comment: I added `:url => "/test"` to my form_for but I am getting another error now

Answer (score 1):

You need to change permitted params

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number, contact_requests: {:id, :message})
```